# Google Drive API - List files in a shared folder that I have not accessed yet

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am trying to automate the downloading of files from a Google Drive shared folder. The contents of the folder change daily. The folder is shared to anyone with a link to the folder.

My problem is that the query does not return the new files that I have not opened yet unless I open the new files in Google Drive.

```
folder_id = 'xxxx...xxx'
results = drive_service.files().list(q=f"parents in '{folder_id}' and trashed = false", fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
```

Is there a way to list files in a shared folder that I have not opened yet?

I tried to negate the sharedWithMe field but it does not work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Yes, there is, but you need to specify that you want to include shared folders into the search

This you can do by setting [`includeItemsFromAllDrives`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) and `supportsAllDrives` to `true`

In python you can implement it with

```
folder_id = 'xxxx...xxx'
results = drive_service.files().list(supportsAllDrives=True, includeItemsFromAllDrives=True, q="parents in '{folder_id}' and trashed = false", fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
```

UPDATE

Mind that `shared with anyone with a link` means that until you open a file, it is not explicitly shared with you and thus won't show up as part of your file list. If you want to change this, you need to ask the owner to specify you as a viewer of the folder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already tried that and it still doesn't work for me. I'm not sure if the account type has an effect on it but I'll try switching to a Service Account.

Comment: Sorry, there was a small typing mistake in my code. Did you try to retrieve the files with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)? What are the permissions you have for those files and folder? Is `folder_id` the id of a folder on the shared drive or the id of the drive itself? Beware that when files are dumped onto a shared drive to which you have access, it is not the same like `sharedWithMe`. Using a service account would only be helpful if the files are shared with the service account or the service accoutn is a member of the shared drive.

Comment: I tried it with the Try this API and I'm getting the same behavior. I'm starting to think that it is designed to behave this way. I have read permission to the folder and its contents. I think the folder was shared with anyone with a link.

Comment: Now I understand why - you say `shared with anyone with a link`. This means that until you open a file, it is not explicitly shared with you and thus won't show up as part of your file list. If you want to change this, you need to ask the owner to specify you as a viewer of the folder.

Comment: Oh I get it now. That's actually the answer I'm looking for. I'll accept your answer but please include your latest comment in the answer above. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If anyone is using the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) linked above, make sure you specify scopes in the Credentials section.  By default, all are selected.  This was my problem: improper scoping.

Comment: @ziganotschka How does the owner make me a viewer of the folder? Thanks! "If you want to change this, you need to ask the owner to specify you as a viewer of the folder."

Comment: @tommy.carstensen by sharing the folder wiht you either via UI or programatically.