# Google Drive API doesn't show shared files

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I need list files shared with me on Google Drive API, but from yesterday to now i'm trying but without success.
I have this single code:

```
  const auth = new google.auth.JWT({
    email: 'xxxxxx@xxxxxx-322013.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
    key: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nfkdajlsfçdklasf-\n',
    scopes: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
    ],
  });
  
  // shared file (owned by regular user and shared with the API service account email)
  const template = '1xcy8PjkRVzjZ-E7jY6gJtSyvSXlCbNyqEYrVS-3nQIY';

  const drive = google.drive({
    version: 'v3',
    auth,
  });

  // entire shared folder (owned by regular user and shared with the API service account email)
  const folderId = '1j0y8rttjNe4JecDH065L9GwEKw_a_nmC';

  const filesDrive = await drive.files.list({
    supportsAllDrives: true,
    includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
    
  });

  console.log(filesDrive);
```

I have tried many combination of parameters, but the **shared file never is displayed** in the filesDrive object.

In the next steps i want to copy the file to the API google drive and replace a few words using docs.

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you know the parent folder of all files of interest (`folderId`), than try to specify it in parents: `const filesDrive = await drive.files.list({
    supportsAllDrives: true,
    includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
    
    q: "'1j0y8rttjNe4JecDH065L9GwEKw_a_nmC' in parents"
  });`

Comment: Also: Above you are saying `files shared with me` and then `shared with the API service account email`. Doublecheck with whom exactly the files have been shared - with you OR the service account?

Comment: @ziganotschka, thanks for the response.
I have tried with the "q:" parameter, but no differences with or without it.
For clarification:
The folder and the file is owned by douglas.rauber@gmail.com and shared with api account.

Comment: Shared with api account means shared with 'xxxxxx@xxxxxx-322013.iam.gserviceaccount.com'?

Comment: Yes.. https://i.imgur.com/OSaRm53.png

Comment: What if you [get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) a file by its Id - does it work?

Comment: No, don't work. Say the file doesn't exists. But i'm running now with other approach, i have created a file with API account and share the file with normal user. Now i can run what i need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62425131/1347572

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I had to share the folder with the service account email (client_email).

1. Go to drive.google.com
2. Right click on the folder you want to see it and click share.
3. Add the service account email to the list.