# find all sheet id in a drive

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api

In their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python), google show the example of how to read a sheet using their API. it requires you to manually find the google sheet ID first from the url. However, I would like to just give a google drive directory, and find the sheet id of all the google sheets in that drive. How can I do that?

Code tried:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


sheetMymeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
parent = PARENTFOLDER_ID

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'keys.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']

credentials = None
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

q = "mimeType = '{}' and parents = '{}'".format(sheetMymeType, parent)
list = drive.files().list(q=q, fields='files(id)').execute()
print(list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you need to use the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3), in specific the [`Files.list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) method.

As you can see in the documentation for [Search files and folders](https://Search%20for%20files%20and%20folders) you can supply a `q` parameter in order to search for a determined type of file. As your goal is `give a google drive directory, and find the sheet id of all the google sheets in that drive` you need to use two [query terms](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-search-terms#file_properties):

- `mimeType` in your case `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet` (you can review the full list of Google Workspace and Drive MIME Types [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/mime-types))
- `parent` the ID of the folder that you want to use.

And, as you need to retrieve those who accomplish the two requeriments you need to use the [`query operator`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-search-terms#operators) `and`

###### `sample.py`

```py
def get_all_sheets_in_folder():
    drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    sheetMymeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
    parent = 'SOME_FOLDER_ID'
    q = "mimeType = '{}' and parents in '{}'".format(sheetMymeType, parent)
    list = drive.files().list(q=q, fields='files(id)').execute()
    print(list)
```

I recommend you review the [`quickstart.py`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python) in order to know how to set up your project.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your detailed help. It all seem to work (connection established) except that it doesn't return any file. I even removed mimeType from the query, but the folder still seem empty. But I know for a fact that there is at least 1 file in it. I have updated the code I tried. Can you give some further advice?

Comment: That's odd, I test my code an is working as expected, ensure that the ID of the folder is correct, if the folder is in a shared folder include the `includeItemsFromAllDrives` parameter => [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62425131/14271633)

Comment: yep that's it! it was in a shared folder. Thank you again!